# How to change navigation animation using Flutter

Tags: animation, flutter, navigation

Is there any way to change the default animation when navigating to/from a page in Flutter?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can achieve this by using [CupertinoPageRoute](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoPageRoute-class.html).
Please check the below code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';


void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Transition Animation Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new FirstPage(),
    );
  }
}

class FirstPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FirstPageState createState() => new _FirstPageState();
}

class _FirstPageState extends State<FirstPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('First Page'),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new RaisedButton(
          child: new Text('Goto Second Page'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).push(new SecondPageRoute());
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondPageRoute extends CupertinoPageRoute {
  SecondPageRoute()
      : super(builder: (BuildContext context) => new SecondPage());


  // OPTIONAL IF YOU WISH TO HAVE SOME EXTRA ANIMATION WHILE ROUTING
  @override
  Widget buildPage(BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation,
      Animation<double> secondaryAnimation) {
    return new FadeTransition(opacity: animation, child: new SecondPage());
  }
}

class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SecondPageState createState() => new _SecondPageState();
}

class _SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Second Page'),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Text('This is the second page'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Some play-around with animation**

```
  // OPTIONAL IF YOU WISH TO HAVE SOME EXTRA ANIMATION WHILE ROUTING
  @override
  Widget buildPage(BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation,
      Animation<double> secondaryAnimation) {
    return new RotationTransition(
        turns: animation,
        child: new ScaleTransition(
          scale: animation,
          child: new FadeTransition(
            opacity: animation,
            child: new SecondPage(),
          ),
        ));
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.  I replaced `MaterialPageRoute` with `CupertinoPageRoute` in my existing app code and got sliding animations.

Comment: @nlern following this one. I'd tested and it works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55340515/3743245

Answer (score 98):

You can use `PageRouteBuilder`.

The following example shows `FadeTransition` when you navigate to second screen.

```dart
Navigator.push(
  context,
  PageRouteBuilder(
    pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) => Page2(),
    transitionDuration: Duration(seconds: 2),
    transitionsBuilder: (_, a, __, c) => FadeTransition(opacity: a, child: c),
  ),
);
```

---

If you're using [`go_router`](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router):

```dart
GoRoute(
  path: '/page2',
  pageBuilder: (_, state) {
    return CustomTransitionPage(
      key: state.pageKey,
      child: Page2(),
      transitionDuration: Duration(seconds: 2),
      transitionsBuilder: (_, a, __, c) => FadeTransition(opacity: a, child: c),
    );
  },
)
```

and then:

```dart
context.go('/page2');
```

Answer (score 56):

You can subclass [MaterialPageRoute](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/MaterialPageRoute-class.html)and override buildTransitions.

Eg:

```
class MyCustomRoute<T> extends MaterialPageRoute<T> {
  MyCustomRoute({ WidgetBuilder builder, RouteSettings settings })
      : super(builder: builder, settings: settings);

  @override
  Widget buildTransitions(BuildContext context,
      Animation<double> animation,
      Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
      Widget child) {
    if (settings.isInitialRoute)
      return child;
    // Fades between routes. (If you don't want any animation,
    // just return child.)
    return new FadeTransition(opacity: animation, child: child);
  }
}
```

to use :

```
new RaisedButton(
                child: new Text('Goto'),
                onPressed: (){
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    new MyCustomRoute(builder: (context) => new SecondPage()),
                  );
                }),
```

Replace fade transition with your animation

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I checked flutter docs for `buildTransitions` (https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ModalRoute/buildTransitions.html) and it seems that I have to write the code for my animation from scratch.  In that case I think using `CupertinoPageRoute` would be simpler.  Nevertheless the solution is helpful.

Comment: Just replacing Fade with our animation wont help us because different animation have different arguments.

Comment: how to use this in names repacements of Navigation?

Answer (score 49):

I have done this by providing my own `builders` with custom map in `pageTransitionsTheme` for the app level theme.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Startup Name Generator Tile',
      home: RandomWords(),
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Colors.white,
        // Add the line below to get horizontal sliding transitions for routes.
        pageTransitionsTheme: PageTransitionsTheme(builders: {TargetPlatform.android: CupertinoPageTransitionsBuilder(),}),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Of course, I didn't add a map entry for ios as I use only android for `TargetPlatform`.

Answer (score 3):

You can also check out `page_transition` package from https://pub.dev/packages/page_transition. This package contains the following different transitions. 
fade,
rightToLeft,
leftToRight,
upToDown,
downToUp,
scale (with alignment),
rotate (with alignment),
size (with alignment),
rightToLeftWithFade,
leftToRightWithFade

Answer (score 0):

the **simplest** way I figured, is to use MaterialPageRoute normally just add:   `fullscreenDialog: true,` inside MaterialPageRoute()

Answer (score 0):

I'm use this in theme data level for target platform is used by user

```
  pageTransitionsTheme: const PageTransitionsTheme(builders: {TargetPlatform.android: CupertinoPageTransitionsBuilder(),}),
```

[image]