# How to add Slide from right navigation in my Flutter application?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I am trying flutter application and I want to navigate to my next screen with Slide navigation. The new screen should come from right with proper animation. In ios it is default but in android it is not happening.

Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: What did you try? Please share the code if possible

Comment: Thanks man but I have got the answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50208048/2863386

Answer (score 9, accepted):

thanks every one but after trying few times and searching here and there, I was able to find the solution.

```
Navigator.of(context).push(new PageRouteBuilder(
    opaque: true,
    transitionDuration: const Duration(durationInMillis),
    pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, _, __) {
      return new NextPage();
    },
    transitionsBuilder: (_, Animation<double> animation, __, Widget child) {

      return new SlideTransition(
      child: child,
        position: new Tween<Offset>(
          begin: const Offset(dx, dy),
          end: Offset.zero,
        ).animate(animation),
      );
    }
));
```

Here if dx>0.0 and dy=0.0 then navigates from right if dy>0.0 and dx= 0.0 then navigates from bottom and durationInMillis is the speed of animation.
Thanks.

Comment: Accept your answer

Comment: Where are you getting dx and dy from?

Answer (score 4):

Just use Flutter `CupertinoPageRoute`

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

.
.
.

Navigator.push(
    context,
    CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (_) => HomeScreen())
);
```