# How to slide to new page on the right instead of the bottom in flutter?

Tags: dart, material-design, flutter, flutter-layout

The default flutter animation to transit a new page into the focus is to slide it up from the bottom. How do i change this behaviors and slide the new page in from the right or left instead?

```
      Navigator.push(
        context,
          new PageRouteBuilder(
          pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, _, __) {
            return new SearchView();
          }
          )
      );
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Change Navigation Animation using Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50196913/how-to-change-navigation-animation-using-flutter)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Check out the [CupertinoPageRoute](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoPageRoute-class.html):

> A modal route that replaces the entire screen with an iOS transition.
>
> The page slides in from the right and exits in reverse. The page also shifts to the left in parallax when another page enters to cover it.
>
> The page slides in from the bottom and exits in reverse with no parallax effect for fullscreen dialogs.

There's a demo of it in the [flutter gallery](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/demo/cupertino/cupertino_navigation_demo.dart) example app:

```
Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).push(
  new CupertinoPageRoute<bool>(
    fullscreenDialog: true,
    builder: (BuildContext context) => new Tab3Dialog(),
  ),
);
```

Comment: change fullscreenDialog  to false, as documentation states: 'The page slides in from the bottom and exits in reverse with no parallax effect for fullscreen dialogs.

'

Answer (score 13):

You can create a function with your desirable animation

```
Route createRoute(Widget page) {
  return PageRouteBuilder(
    pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) => page,
    transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
      const begin = Offset(1.0, 0.0);
      const end = Offset.zero;
      const curve = Curves.ease;

      var tween = Tween(begin: begin, end: end).chain(CurveTween(curve: curve));

      return SlideTransition(
        position: animation.drive(tween),
        child: child,
      );
    },
  );
}
```

And call it each time you push to a new screen

```
Navigator.of(context).push(createRoute(SearchView()))
```

If you want to change the direction you need to change the offset of `begin`
If you want to change the effect you need to change `SlideTransition`

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    const MaterialApp(
      home: Page1(),
    ),
  );
}

class Page1 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Page1({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).push(_createRoute());
          },
          child: const Text('Open Page Two'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Route _createRoute() {
  return PageRouteBuilder(
    pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) => const Page2(),
    transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
      const begin = Offset(1.0, 0.0);
      const end = Offset.zero;
      const curve = Curves.ease;

      var tween = Tween(begin: begin, end: end).chain(CurveTween(curve: curve));

      return SlideTransition(
        position: animation.drive(tween),
        child: child,
      );
    },
  );
}

class Page2 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Page2({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: const Center(
        child: Text('Hi, This is Page Two! (slided-In from Right)'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This creates a two page route with transitions, see [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/animation/page-route-animation) for more info

Answer (score 0):

A modified version of Matteo Antolini's answer:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ScreenNavigator {
  final BuildContext cx;
  ScreenNavigator({
    required this.cx,
  });
  navigate(Widget page, Tween<Offset> tween) {
    Navigator.push(
      cx,
      PageRouteBuilder(
        pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) {
          return page;
        },
        transitionDuration: Durations.long1,
        transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
          // create CurveTween
          const Curve curve = Curves.ease;
          final CurveTween curveTween = CurveTween(curve: curve);
          // chain Tween with CurveTween
          final Animatable<Offset> chainedTween = tween.chain(curveTween);
          final Animation<Offset> offsetAnimation =
              animation.drive(chainedTween);
          return SlideTransition(position: offsetAnimation, child: child);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NavigatorTweens {
  static Tween<Offset> bottomToTop() {
    const Offset begin = Offset(0.0, 1.0);
    const Offset end = Offset(0.0, 0.0);
    return Tween(begin: begin, end: end);
  }

  static Tween<Offset> topToBottom() {
    const Offset begin = Offset(0.0, -1.0);
    const Offset end = Offset(0.0, 0.0);
    return Tween(begin: begin, end: end);
  }

  static Tween<Offset> leftToRight() {
    const Offset begin = Offset(-1.0, 0.0);
    const Offset end = Offset(0.0, 0.0);
    return Tween(begin: begin, end: end);
  }

  static Tween<Offset> rightToLeft() {
    const Offset begin = Offset(1.0, 0.0);
    const Offset end = Offset(0.0, 0.0);
    return Tween(begin: begin, end: end);
  }
}
```

you can copy+paste it in a file and use it across your app like:

```
onTap: () {

   ScreenNavigator(cx: context)
   .navigate(Page(),NavigatorTweens.leftToRight());

},
```

to have better understanding of page sliding transition, [read the official document](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/animation/page-route-animation)