# create a custombottomsheet in a seperate class in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i am using flutter for creating a web screen and want to create a  custom bottomSheet in seperate stateless class. i want the customBottomSheet to appear from the right side of the screen and cover the half right side of the screen.

currently i have an inkwell and on the click of that inkwell i will be showing this bottom sheet. you can see the image to understand my requirements more clearly:
[image: click on it to see the functionality i want to implement]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [transition builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50196913/how-to-change-navigation-animation-using-flutter) or [endDrawer](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/drawer#interactive-example) widget.

**Transition builder approach:**

You define your UI in a `Stateless/Stateful` widget class and push a new route to the current context.
Key to achieving half screen would be adding margin to the parent widget of your UI class and transparent scaffold.

**Drawer approach:**

This is a more use case specific, built-in, and optimized way to show the popup.
It will handle the right to left animation and you can set the width as well without extra code.

Check out more details on the mentioned links!