# How to "push" in new screens on the screen stack from another direction in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I´m adding a new screen to the screen stack as follows:

```
Navigator.of(context).push(
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => const NewItem(),
  ),
);
```

Now I want the new screen to **slide in from left to right (instead from right to left which is the default)**. Therefore I´ve created an "unhandy" solution using PageRoutebuilder() and SlideTransition() to somehow "rebuild" the native animation (but from the other side).

**Isn´t there an easier or more elagant way** to simply change the direction in the MaterialPageRouteWidget? Something like an extended class that overrides some specific properties (I alread had a look at this but couldn´t find a solution).

Comment: Hello, check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50196913/how-to-change-navigation-animation-using-flutter

Comment: That´s exactly the way I do it at the moment as written above. However, the animation differs from the MaterialPageRoute Animation in some aspects, so the question is if there is a way to "extend" and modify the MaterialPageRoute animation in an easy way.

Answer (score 0):

Purely theoretically you can override globally for all screens the transition animation using `ThemeData.pageTransitionsTheme`. In it, apply the correct transition animation based on the route name. The transition animations themselves can be unified as separate methods with a "the screen we go to" parameter.